# Changing icon of app using CandyBar failing on OS X 10.4.11 Tiger

Tags: icon, macos

So I'm using OS X 10.4.11 Tiger on Power PC (old iBook G4 - gift/joke for Christmas) and I installed and am happily using CandyBar to customize the icons.

However, I want to customize the icon for TenFourFox, as it isn't all that esthetic. I have the .png, .ico, and .icns of the icon I want to use, but whenever I try to use CandyBar to change the icon, it just takes the placeholder for that type of file, as you can see here:

Default TenFourFox in CandyBar:
[image: default tenfourfox in candybar]

Trying custom icon (drag-and-drop):
[image: custom icon]

Does anyone have any clue what is going on and how to fix it?

BTW, I'm using CandyBar 2.6.1, if that could be part of it. The newest version only supports 10.5+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.6.1 unfortunately didn't have Pixadex built in, and those image wells only supported the actual `Icon` of whatever it is that gets dropped in them. For example, the .png files you dropped in currently have the icon of:

[image]

and that's exactly what it's giving you. So essentially what gets dropped in those image wells needs to be represented (having the icon) with what you drop in there. If you try dragging anything that already has a custom icon associated with it into the image well you'll quickly understand how it works.

I found the best way to manage icons before CandyBar 3 was to use Pixadex in addition to CandyBar 2, since it allows drag and drop between the two apps. It's precisely why they eventually merged the two, because they really did [belong together](https://web.archive.org/web/20131110005844/http://iconfactory.com/software/pixadex).

• [Pixadex 2.0.2 download](https://web.archive.org/web/20131110005844/http://files.iconfactory.net/software/Pixadex_2.0.2.dmg) (works with 10.2+) and [other older icon related things](http://www.pure-mac.com/facelift.html).

Comment: Informative post. Will try this out and if it works, mark it as answer!

Comment: Do you know of any good sites where icons can be downloaded? I tried the icons on the CandyBar download site, but I didn't really like most of them. Comment if you know please! Thanks!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness * try [here](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/graphics-roundups/6-places-to-find-superb-high-quality-mac-icons/), [here](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/graphics-roundups/over-55-beautiful-folder-icons-for-os-x/), and  [here](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/graphics-roundups/52-superb-free-icon-sets-for-mac/).